# Chilkat how to get not safeguarded mime?

Tags: go, chilkat

I create chilkat `mime` object from ready `string`:

```
mimeObject := chilkat.NewMime()
mimeLoaded := mimeObject.LoadMime(mime)
```

Then if I append `mime` to inbox folder:

```
imap.AppendMime(mailbox, mime)
```

Cyrillic characters are broken in inbox folder.

I tried to get not safeguarded mime string the following ways:

```
fmt.Println(string(mimeObject.GetMimeBytes()))
fmt.Println(mimeObject.GetMime())
```

But everything give safeguarded like this:

```
=D0=9F=D0=A0=D0=98=D0=92=D0=95=D0=A2
```

or

```
 =?utf-8?B?w5DCpcOQwqDDkOKAosOQIMOQwqXDkMKjw5DCr8OQwqfDkMucw5DihKIgSE9XIEFSRSBZT1U=?=
```

And the next function gives same result"

```
email.SaveEml("MIME.txt")
```

File MIME.txt is safeguarded

Also the problem is that when I try to get subject by 2 following methods it also cuts cyrillic characters..:

```
email.Subject()
email.GetHeaderField("Subject")
```

I have read this: http://www.chilkatforum.com/questions/13011/chilkat-activex-mail-defaulting-to-quoted-printable-when-trying-to-send-8bit and I couldn't figure out how to do that.

So how can I get not safeguarded mime string and append it to inbox and make subject, body and other appear properly ? Should I use some extra mime parser ?